# Custom validaton messages not working on Symfony 3

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have the following declaration in my user class (Symfony 3, it's an entity class):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank (
 *  groups={"registration"}, 
 *  message = "test"
 * )
 * @Assert\Email(
 *  message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email.",
 *  groups={"registration"}
 * )
 */
private $email;
```

Everything works fine, except that I can't set a message, instead of my message ('test' for example) a default "This value should not be blank" is displayed.

Yes, I do have

```
framework: 
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
```

In my config.yml

Edit: and yes I cleared cache by executing:

```
sudo php bin/console cache:clear
```

Edit2: Please note that it actually DOES go through validation, Symfony sees that the email is required, it displays a message if I leave the field empty, it's just that it is not my message, Symfony somehow doesn't see the "message" part.

Edit3: Now, after removing the groups={"registration"} part, as well as changing (in controller)

```
$errors = $validator->validate($user, null, array('registration'));
```

to

```
$errors = $validator->validate($user, null);
```

(removed array('registration'))

the correct message is displayed. However this is not a solution. I need to use groups.

**Edit 4:**
I'll get crazy...

If I enter no email, and then:

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($user, null, array('registration'));
dump($errors);
```

(Notice the "dump" function call) then I see an incorect message displayed on a page (This value should not be blank) but... when I enter the profiler->debug page (the dev tools at the bottom) then I can see that a correct (my) message is there...

Furthermore in profiler->form errors is this incorect message on the list (as only one item) but... it says it refers to a field named "plainPassword" which is not in the form, and does NOT belong to the "registration" group, so it should not be validated in the first place.

What's going on there?

Comment: did you put this ? 
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

Comment: Yes, Samia.  And btw - there are no errors/warning in logs.

Comment: Could you please look at my updated question? I removed validation groups and it now displays my message and that's fine, but I need those groups.

Answer (score 2):

Can You try this?

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, unique=true)
*
* 
* @Assert\NotBlank(
*  message = "The box cant be left blank")
*
*
* @Assert\Email(
*  message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email."
* 
* )
*/
private $email;
```

Comment: No, it didn't help. I see you removed the groups={"registration"}, part, but, while validating, I use this: $validator = $this->get('validator');
   $errors = $validator->validate($user, null, array('registration')); Besides it DOES validate, it's just that the message is not mine.

Comment: please check this, https://github.com/symfony/validator. I hope it will help you figure out the issue

Comment: OK, thanks for trying :) It looks like indeed I'll have to look at Symfony code (unfortunatelly, because I've just started with Symfony and researching its source wasn't very high on my todo list :) ). Thanks again.